# C bsearch always returns pointer=NULL

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bsearch

Can someone tell me why in this program bsearch fuction always returns pointer=NULL??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    char eye[15];
};



int komparator (const void* a, const void *b)
{
    struct data *aa = (struct data *)a;
    struct data *bb = (struct data *)b;
    return (aa->age-bb->age);
}

int main ()
{
    char *NAME[10]={"Ola","Tola","Jola","Zosia","Jan","Adam","Ala","Basia","Tom","Jacek"};
    char *COLOR[10]={"zielone", "brazowe", "niebieskie", "niebieskie", "zielone", "brazowe", "brazowe", "niebieskie", "czarne", "niebieskie"};

    struct data (*pointer)[5];
    struct data people[2][5];
    pointer=people;

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2*5;i++)
    {
        strcpy((*pointer)[i].name,NAME[i]);
        strcpy((*pointer)[i].eye,COLOR[i]);
        (*pointer)[i].age=rand()%(40-18)+18;
    }

    qsort(people,2*5,sizeof(struct data),komparator);

 // here is the problem:        
    int wanted = 18;
    struct data *found=(struct data*) bsearch(&wanted,people,2*5,sizeof(struct data),komparator);

    if(found!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Found name is: %s,  eye's: %s, age: %d\n",found->name,found->eye,found->age);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Didnt find \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please focus on the part with bsearch, because other thing working well.

I will be very grateful :)

Comment: why defining a 2D array & a pointer when you can just do `struct data people[10];` ?

Comment: `komparator` can not be applied to `&wanted` as `int*`.

Comment: I was asked for this in my university :S multidimentional array works in qsort, which has similar arguments so i don't think that this is a problem

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why? whats wrong there and how i could fix it?

Comment: Because `komparator ` requires `struct data *`, not `int *`. try `int wanted = 18;` --> `struct data wanted = {"", 18, ""};`

Comment: I did the same code with one dimentional array of structers and i have the same result ;/

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  WOW it works now! thanks!

Comment: or Make key the first member. I.E. `struct data
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    char eye[15];
};` --> `struct data
{
 int age;
 char name[10];
 char eye[15];
};` then `int wanted = 18;`...

Comment: The posted code seems to be missing the statement: `#include <time.h>`   followed be: `srand( time() );`

Comment: regarding: `(*pointer)[i].age=rand()%(40-18)+18;`  due to order of operations in C, this line becomes: `(*pointer)[i].age=rand()%40;`  perhaps you meant: `(*pointer)[i].age= (rand()%(40-18)) +18;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem is that komparator requires type (struct data *), so

```
int wanted=18;
```

is the mistake and after changing it to

```
struct data wanted = {"", 18, ""};
```

everything works :)

@BLUEPIXY helped :)